# Can I mount the same artifactory repository to more than 100 machines using webdav , davfs2

Tags: artifactory, webdav

Can artifactory support multiple mount points?

Will there be a delay in service due to traffic?

Comment: You mean mounting 100 file systems into Artifactory for its storage backend? Why? Or you want to access Artifactory from 100 client machines? But that would be via HTTPS, no?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56422772/can-i-mount-an-artifactory-repository-as-a-nfs-system

Comment: I want to access Artifactory from 100 client machines, through webdav, will it serve at same speed to all client machines, is there any limit on how many client machines to connect